# Remove element of array from document in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb

How to remove element of array from document? Example document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("599eab4cf51e0718a42bc9de"),
    "premises" : {
        "599eab4cf51e0718a42bc9dd" : {
            "id" : ObjectId("599eab4cf51e0718a42bc9dd"),
            "typeOfPremises" : "",
            "level" : "",
            "orientation" : "",
            "view" : "",
            "separateEntrance" : null,
            "size" : "232323",
            "comment" : ""
        }
    }
}
```

I want remove premises where id = 599eab4cf51e0718a42bc9dd.

Comment: Will you please update your post with schema so that I can help you correctly.because you use 599eab4cf51e0718a42bc9dd as a key.So I am thinking on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. As this contains nested documents so that you need to access everything with its objectId.Here Batch is nothing but the variable you require the model. Like `var Batch=require('../models/schema');` As you didn't mention your schema so that I assumed some variables. If you mention the schema it will be clear for you. Change it with your code. Hope this helps.

```
//Deleting
app.delete('/:Id/premises/:premisesId/599eab4cf51e0718a42bc9dd/:numId',function (req, res, next) {
    Batch.findById(req.params.Id, function (err, batch) {
    if (err) throw err;
    batch.premises.findById(req.params.premisesId, function (err, bat) {
     if (err) throw err;
    bat.599eab4cf51e0718a42bc9dd.id(req.params.numId).remove();
        bat.save(function (err, resp) {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.json(resp);
        });
    });
});


//Updating

app.put(('/:Id/premises/:premisesId/599eab4cf51e0718a42bc9dd/:numId',function (req, res, next) {
    Batch.findById(req.params.Id, function (err, batch) {
        if (err) throw err;
         batch.premises.findById(req.params.premisesId, function (err, bat) {
         if (err) throw err;
       bat.599eab4cf51e0718a42bc9dd.id(req.params.numId).remove();
        bat.599eab4cf51e0718a42bc9dd.push(req.body);
        bat.save(function (err, batc) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('Updated!');
            res.json(batc);
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: You want to update the document by removing  id = 599eab4cf51e0718a42bc9dd.Am I right???If I am right I will update my answer with update code

Comment: Yes, I want this.